Oracle APEX Translation process fails
When I try to translate my APEX application, only a few parts are translated (about 10 out of 100-200) and the translation repository does not recognise a large part of the translated words. I know that the XLIFF file is valid (I have validated it). The main language is set to English and the target language is German.
The translation repository should recognise the translation correctly and the pages should be translated. I followed these instructions: https://www.triology.de/blog/datenbankanwendungen-oracle-apex.
I researched the problem, but I couldn't find a similar problem or why it might be happening.
